# Characterization of Integral Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We can show that in an Integral Domain I if $x^2=1$ then $x=\pm 1$.

Is the converse true?

i.e if for any x in I with $x^2=1 \implies x=\pm1$ then I is an Integral Domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take $\mathbb{Z}/4$, for example, where it is well-known all squares are 0 or 1 (depending on how they reduce in $\mathbb{Z}/2$).  So $x^2=1$ iff $x=\pm 1$ but this isn't an integral domain.

Comment: are there any equivalent forms of being I.D?

Comment: One is the cancelation Property, but are there any other equivalent forms to the statement of Integral Domain?

Comment: no zero divisors, 0 is a prime ideal, $A\to A_0=\langle A-\{0\}\rangle^{-1}A$ is injective, ...

Comment: $A→A_0=⟨A−\{0\}⟩^{−1}A $ is injective, I could not understand this. Will you please explain this to me.

Comment: $A-\{0\}$ is a subset of $A$ so has multiplicative closure $S=\langle A-\{0\}\rangle$.  Now take [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) $S^{-1}A$ of $A$.